# How can you display option sets within a SSRS report?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, report, fetchxml, dynamics-365

I'm new to Stack overflow and new to SSRS report building. I'm currently building a report that needs to display each option from and option set in a different column I also need to pull date a last and next date range for each option it is page grouped by a company name and then further grouped by the employee's full name. any help would be very much appreciated.

## Excel mock-up

[image: excel mock-up]

## Report table layout

[image: report table layout]

I need it to out put like the Excel image ideally if possible, I've found the value id's but i'm stumped as to how if I can at all display them in the columns I've labelled.

Comment: You'll need to supply more information. Edit your question and show some sample data and how you expect the output to look (do a mock-up in Excel of something). Also state what you have tried so far.

Comment: I don’t think you can do all this in fetchxml.

Comment: It would also help us to understand what you have tried so far.  What piece are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to use a matrix control in your report. It will display your values in a pivot view like Excel.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-matrix-report-builder-and-ssrs)

[image]